# How do I seperate my SQL and Business Logic in this example?

Tags: php, abstraction, data-layers

I have been looking for help online on how to design my php classes to separate my business logic and my data layers. I had started to design a class I thought was pretty cool but then discovered PDO and ADODB and had a nice facepalm moment realizing I was recreating the wheel. My problem now is I still don't quite understand how to separate my logic and all my SQL queries.

I stripped out mostly everything from my DB schema and put down these two tables because I think they'd be pretty easy to understand. Let's say I have Files with the path where they are saved on my server which are in Directories (these Directories can be in other Directories). Let's say I'll need basic features like fetching the root Directory from one of my files or get a list of Directories inside the current Directory.

```
+--------------------+ +----------------+
| Files              | | Directories    |
+--------------------+ +----------------+
| id                 | | id             |
| name               | | name           |
| path               | | directory_id   |
| directory_id       | +----------------+
+--------------------+
```

Would a well designed class look like this:

```
class Files {
    public function __construct( $file_id ) {}
    public function getDirectory() {}
    public function getRootDirectory() {}
    public function getPath() {}
    public function move( $directory_id ) {}
}

class Directories {
    public function __construct( $directory_id ) {}
    public function getRootDirectory() {}
    public function move( $directory_id ) {}
    public function listContent() {}
}
```

Where I'd fetch all the data for my objects in the constructor using the ID passed through the constructor? Should I pass a PDO object in the constructor as well or am I missing some valuable design pattern? Should all the SQL be hardcoded in here? One thing I get with PDO is that I could switch from MySQL to MSSQL very easily but both have differences in the syntax of their SQL so wouldn't still cause me problems?

I know these are more theoretical questions without ONE good answer but I lack work colleagues to discuss this with (I'm not kidding when I say they don't even know what a design pattern is) so I find myself turning to the web. If my question is too vague feel free to suggest a good discussion type place I could ask this kind of stuff and I'd be extremely grateful :)

Comment: i don't think there are any reasons to separate mysql and app logic. that is usually done for logic-presentation

Comment: So the classes I wrote there would be fine? A change in DMBS would mean I'd have to go and modify the SQL statements in every one of those classes (since some DBMS have differences in their SQL syntax)?

Comment: the ORM solution resolves that problem of DBMS change, by abstracting the interface.

Comment: ah ok now I got you. Posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell just how much this would apply to your real-world situation, but you should probably look up what an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) can do for you.  There are many, many very useful ORM solutions out there, that can make this stuff much simpler.  They're not all right for every solution, of course, but ORMs can help you implement your logic in the middle tier, where it belongs (usually).

Comment: Thank you, I think part of my problem was that I didn't know the nomenclature so all I could find were resources on data access layers. I'll read up on ORMs :)

Comment: @Gazillion: you'll find them to be VERY interesting and useful.  I recommend Hibernate, but it's just one of many different ORMs.

Comment: I'm working in PHP so I think I won't be able to use Hibernate (it's just for Java right?). I've found Doctrine, PorkDB, and Propel. I'll try and figure out how to use these correctly and see if I can really up my programming-game :)

Comment: So by using an ORM I will never need to write SQL because objects will be automatically created from my table's schema? So when I want to go get a row I do it through the object's methods and the driver between the database and my code takes care of generating SQL? Sorry if the answers are obvious, I'm just trying to make sure I'm on the right track!

Comment: @Gazillion: Yes, that's the general point of the ORMs; they provide the abstraction layer between your object representation of your data and the structured (relational) storage of that data.  They're very handy!  For example, retrieving an instance of a row (object) is usually as simple as passing to the object instance the criteria on which you want to find it; the ORM will handle the translation of that criteria into a SQL query, perform the retrieval, and perform the mapping between the recordset and the object(s) to be returned.  Useful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

As readed from your comment if you want to keep your SQL working with all DMBS I think you can use some SQL Abstraction Layer.

I suggest you `Zend_DB_Select` http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html

If you read its feature it's stated:

- Database-independent abstraction of some parts of the SQL query;